# $\mathbb{CP}^2$ realizable as boundary of compact smooth $5$-manifold?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory, symplectic-geometry

As the title says, can $\mathbb{CP}^2$ be realized as the boundary of a compact smooth $5$-manifold?

Comment: No. The Euler characteristic of the boundary of a compact manifold is even.

Comment: See also this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184435/can-mathbb-cpn-be-the-boundary-of-a-compact-manifold?rq=1