# Can $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$ become the boundary of certain compact manifold with boundary?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've known from [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184435/can-mathbb-cpn-be-the-boundary-of-a-compact-manifold) that $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ can become the boundary of certain compact manifold iff n odd. What about $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$?

Comment: $\Bbb{R}P^{2k}$ cannot be the boundary of any compact manifold. This can be proven by Poincare-Lefschetz duality and betti number argument.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}P^{2k+1}$ indeed bounds something according to [this math overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8829/what-manifolds-are-bounded-by-rpodd)

Comment: @Kevin.S Why not an official answer?

Comment: Another way is to use the result of Pontryagin and Thom that asserts that a closed smooth manifold is nullcobordant iff its Stiefel-Whitney numbers vanish.

Comment: It's probably simpler to use the fact that $\mathbb{R}P^{2k}$ is non-orientable.

Comment: So is the boundary of compact manifold orientable ? I'm not quite sure.@Kajelad

Comment: @Sqr: Not necessarily. A non-orientable manifold can be a boundary. An example is the Klein bottle. Another is $\mathbb{RP}^2\times S^1$ which bounds $\mathbb{RP}^2\times D^2$.